# Add second price calculation factor to cart item

Tags: price, event-observer, custom-options

I need to add a second price factor to the cart.

Besides amount/quantity I have to add a second (integer) value that comes from a custom option, so the calculation isn't

**base price x amount**

but

**base price x "custom option value" x amount**

Background: Custom option is "number of days" for a rentable product.

Note: I do not need to incorporate anything after the checkout process, since the Magento install is configured to act as "inquiry only" system (no invoicing and such).

I presume there is some event I can observe for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use observes both `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_update_items_after` events.

Those event provide two parameter one is current  `Quote item quote_item` and other is `product object`.

See  `Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));`

Create Custom Module at config.xml  code  look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento55235>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento55235>
  </modules>
  <global>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <magento55235>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento55235_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento55235_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento55235>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento55235/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>resetMyPrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento55235/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>AllresetMyPrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

On Observer file reset product price by s`etCustomPrice()` and  `setOriginalCustomPrice()`

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento55235_Model_Observer
{

            public function resetMyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {

                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $basePrice = $product->getPrice();
                $customOptions = $quote_item->getBuyRequest()->getOptions();
                //using $customOptions get option value 
                /* th */
                $price = $basePrice * $numberofdays * $integerField ;
                $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

            }

            public function AllresetMyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {

                  // Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_after', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
                  /* need to same action here */

            }

}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks Amit. There's just one typo in your config.xml (</helpers> should be removed).

Comment: Is there an event for "cart view"? Basically it works fine after adding an item, but I also need to modify the price when just viewing the cart. I can't seem to find an event for that ...